# Grouping boxplots in Seaborn, coming from multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have two dataframes and can produce separate boxplots from them - one boxplot per column - and have them in the same plot. These two dataframes are IDENTICAL in size and column names but they represent different scenarios. What I want to do, is basically concatenate the two plots and have a pair of boxplots on the same column name (eg. 4 Bytes), so can be easily compared.

My dataframes have this form:

```
+---------+---------+---------+
| 1 Byte  | 2 Bytes | 4 Bytes |
+---------+---------+---------+
| Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 |
| Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 |
| Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

and one boxplot is created per column.

I spent my entire afternoon with no success, even though I think that I'm missing something obvious with actually concatenating and melting the two dataframes. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

This is my expected result

[image]

**EDIT2:**

Added a minimal example:

```
df_new['ID']='1'
df_old['ID']='2'

both = pd.concat((df_new, df_old))
sns.boxplot(both, showfliers=False, hue='ID')
```

But unfortunately it complains with: Could not interpret input 'ID'

Comment: I added a minimum example, please take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `seaborn`:

```
sns.boxplot(data=pd.concat([df1,df2], keys=('df1','df2'))
              .stack().reset_index(level=[0,2], name='value'),
            x='level_2', hue='level_0', y='value'
)
```

Output:

[image]

---

**Update**: To match your output (with `Data Size` label):

```
sns.boxplot(data=pd.concat([df1,df2], keys=('df1','df2'))
              .stack().rename_axis(index=['dataset', '', 'Data Size'])
              .reset_index(level=[0,2], name='Lat'),
            x='Data Size', hue='dataset', y='Lat'
)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I am already using seaborn, however even with your example I am getting: ValueError: Could not interpret input 'Data Size'. This is the line I am calling: sns.boxplot(data=both.stack().reset_index(level=[0,1], name='Latency'), x='Data_Size', hue='level_0', y='Latency')

Comment: Yes, it's `x='level_2'` not `'x='Data_Size'`. `Data_Size` is *not* a column in the data. See updated answer for the correct label:

Comment: Yes! I'm almost there! This is where I am now, though: https://imgur.com/vzSOzTU. Could this be because of my data?

Comment: It is because of your data. The two datasets are of different scales. Try `logscale` on the axis.